# Error 404 enn una ruta en laravel con livewire

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Tengo un problema con laravel. Hice una ruta y hace unos días funcionaba bien, pero ahora no sé por qué no funciona. Estoy trabajando con livewire, así que en el archivo de ruta este es mi código:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Livewire;

Route::get('/dashboard', [Admin\AdminController::class, 'index']) -> name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/productos', Livewire\Admin\ProductList::class) -> name('admin.products');
Route::get('/productos/crear', Livewire\Admin\ProductCreate::class) -> name('admin.products.create');
Route::get('/productos/editar/{product}', Livewire\Admin\ProductEdit::class) -> name('admin.products.edit');
Route::post('/productos/fotos/{product}', [Admin\ProductController::class, 'photos']) -> name('admin.products.photos');
```

Todas las rutas funcionan, menos '/productos/crear'. Aparece un error 404.

Y este es mi controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Subcategory;
use App\Models\Brand;

class ProductCreate extends Component
{

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.product-create');
    }
}
```

Revisé todos los nombres de los archivos para asegurarme de que son correctos y no puedo encontrar la solución. ¡Ayuda por favor!

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar el log? Se encuentra en `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` Si el archivo es muy grande abre el archivo, borra todo y guarda los cambios, luego abre tu ruta para que te aparezca el error 404 y revisa el log, debería aparecer solo lo relacionado a ese error

Comment: @HeytalePazguato al ser un 404 no hay log. En el logo aparecen otro tipo de errores, menos ese, xq básicamente es una redirección a una url existente, la 404. Pero ya lo resolví, ahora lo coloco en otro comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEMA RESUELTO

Tenía otro archivo de rutas, donde la primera parte era una variable, la segunda "productos" y la 3era parte el slug. Eso entraba en conflicto con "admin/productos/crear" y daba 404. Simple, pero me volví loco hasta darme cuenta.